# Como Gerar/Calcular o Valor das Tabelas Binomial Poisson e Normal em Java

Tags: java, combinações

Estou a fazer um trabalho em Java para calcular as probabilidades estatisticas, não sei é como gerar as tabelas de Poisson Binomial e Normal para prosseguir. Por exemplo:

```
X~Bi(5,0.05)
```

Neste caso `X` tende para uma binomial, eu teria que ir à tabela das Probabilidades Binomiais procurar onde o `n` é 5 e o `p` 0.05 e o `X` o que o utilizador disser. O problema está em gerar o valor da Tabela.

Comment: talvez isso ajude: [Algorithm to generate Poisson and binomial random numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1241605/1964435)

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca Apache Commons Math provê implementações matemáticas e estatísticas, inclusive da [Distribuição de Poisson](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/PoissonDistribution.html).

Dê uma olhada na documentação para ver as possibilidades de uso:

- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/index.html